# Magento 2: After Customer Login Get Cart Information?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, magento2.1.6

Customer has already Items in Cart. He is logout.

I'm using `customer_login` observer. It is correct?

**How to get customers all cart information after his successfull login?**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class CustomerLoginAfter implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {

        $quoteItemsAll = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        echo count($quoteItemsAll);
        exit;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

It gives 0 count. While I already have 6 Items in Cart.

How to get customer's previous quote & it's items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should add  `Magento_Checkout` as **a depend module** for your moule  `Custom_Module`.

This depend tag use for as at `customer_login` event magento merge current quote(Quote which is created before login ) and already existing code(active quote which exists in customer account).

This depends make an `<sequence>` tag make sequence in execution of this two module ,First fire checkout module then your module means you will get merge quote object

```
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
    </sequence>
```

Then at your observer ,you can get item qty by below code:

```
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsQty() * 1
```

And to get all  visible items:

```
$quoteItemsAll = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Comment: `$quoteItemsAll = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();` it's still giving zero

Comment: this solution does not work. I added magento_quote and magento_checkout in the sequence and i still get null.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class CustomerLoginAfter implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $quote;
    protected $quoteItem;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem) {
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteItem = $quoteItem;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();

        $quoteAll = $this->quote->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)->getData();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($quoteAll);


        $quoteItemAll = $this->quoteItem->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $quoteAll[0]['entity_id'])->getData();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($quoteItemAll);
        exit;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Please let me know if have better solution

Comment: Where can I see the result of above event?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\MagentoCustomer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface {
   /**     
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
 */
    protected $quoteRepository;


 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {        
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();       
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        if($customerId){            
        //method 1
            $quote= $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->loadByCustomer($customerId); 
            $cartItems1=$quote->getAllItems();
            echo count(cartItems1);echo '<br>';
        //(OR) method 2
          $customerQuote = $this->quoteRepository->getForCustomer($customerId);
        $cartItems2=$customerQuote->getAllItems();
        echo count($cartItems2);echo '<br>';
       //(OR) method 3
        $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->load($quoteId);
        $cartItems3=$quote->getAllItems();
        echo count($cartItems3);
       }
    }
}
```

> $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->loadByCustomer($customerId);

OR

> $this->quoteRepository->getForCustomer($customerId);

OR

> $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->load($quoteId);

All above methods can help you to fetch current customer cart items.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

declare observer

Demo/CustomerQuote/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost">
        <observer name="quote_cart" instance="Demo\CustomerQuote\Observer\QuoteObserver"/>
    </event>

</config>
```

add observer class

Demo/CustomerQuote/Observer/QuoteObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Demo\CustomerQuote\Observer;

use Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class QuoteObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $cartHelper;

    public function __construct(
        Cart $cartHelper
    )
    {
        $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {    
        $items = $this->cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
        // Use this instead counting items
        $countedCartItems = $this->cartHelper->getSummaryCount();
        \Zend_Debug::dump(count($items));
        \Zend_Debug::dump($countedCartItems);
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give 0 as output