# how to refresh mini cart programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

after customer login ,i am add filter on current customer quote, and remove items form quote which are not match. so item are delete successfully but  front side in minicart  cart item count are not updated .

use : "customer_login" event

Comment: Use section.xml file to unvalidate cart after login

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/sections.xml

file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="customer/account/logout">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="customer/account/loginPost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="customer/account/createPost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="customer/ajax/login">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/delete">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/updatePost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/updateItemOptions">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/couponPost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/estimatePost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/onepage/saveOrder">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
        <section name="last-ordered-items"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/sidebar/removeItem">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/payment-information">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
        <section name="last-ordered-items"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/guest-carts/*/payment-information">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/guest-carts/*/selected-payment-method">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/selected-payment-method">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

In every action your mini cart will refresh.

Comment: will it refresh without page reload ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution :
 i am remove items form quote based on my custom filter after customer login.so i am used customer_login event.

File : Doyenhub\RestrictCustomer\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Doyenhub\RestrictCustomer\Observer\CustomerLoginAfter" />
    </event>
```

And My Observer class is 
Doyenhub\RestrictCustomer\Observer\CustomerLoginAfter.php

```
class CustomerLoginAfter implements ObserverInterface {

        protected $quoteRepository;

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem
        ) {
            $this->_quoteItem = $quoteItem;
            $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        }    

     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
                $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                //$quoteId = get quote id 
                $cartData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository')->get($quoteId);
                $items = $cartData->getAllItems();
                 foreach ($items as $item) 
                 {
                  $quoteItem = $this->_quoteItem->load($item->getItemId());
                  $quoteItem->delete();//delete item
                 }
            //=======referesh quote=======
                 $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
                 $quote->setCustomerId($customer->getId()); // Whatever you want to update
                 $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        }
}
```

Comment: worked for me. but if some one follow Jay Patel instruction, please read this instruction too.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/247993/70258

Comment: well, in my site, it refreshed the quote, but it have another issue appear after i login: "Cart 14985 does not contain item 312"

Comment: i guess this is the answer. I've follow this link and override the CartItemPersister.php
http://frankclark.xyz/magento2-1-programatically-create-order