# Magento 2: Mini cart not updating while delete a product from observer

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I see my mini cart not updating its items when I delete an item from the cart programmatically.

but the cart updating perfectly as per my requirement only after I added a new item into cart or any cart event-triggered non programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this issue by creating a file `app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\section.xml` using following code inside your extension folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="extension/controller/action">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

In this action parameter name, you have to pass the full action (For ex. checkout/cart/add ) in which cart is updated. It means you programmatically delete or add a product to cart to the shopping cart.

Also, you can add below code in your observer to refresh the quote for the customer.

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
$quote->setCustomerId($customer->getId()); // Whatever you want to update
$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

> Reference: [how to refresh mini cart programmatically in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203341/how-to-refresh-mini-cart-programmatically-in-magento2)

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: "You have to pass the full action (Forex. checkout/cart/add ) "I don't understand this point. which path i have to place here?

Comment: This is for controller action.

Comment: Have you tried it @SanjunDev?

Comment: No! it is just hold. anyway it seems to be work.